# Django - a migration was detected, but saying no migrations to apply

Tags: django

I added a new field `slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)` to a model. A new migration was successfully detected.

```
(venv) 192-168-1-201:shop jinx$ python manage.py makemigrations book
Migrations for 'book':
  book/migrations/0014_book_slug.py
    - Add field slug to book
```

But when I tried to apply the migration, it said:

```
(venv) 192-168-1-201:shop jinx$ python manage.py migrate book
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: book
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

The table is not updating, not adding a new column. 
And --fake doesn't help as well.

```
(venv) 192-168-1-201:shop jinx$ python manage.py migrate --fake book
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: book
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I have faced this problem for serval times, but each time I fixed it somehow. Now I want to know what causes this issue?

**Fields in the model:**

```
class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=191, unique=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)  # new field 

    pub_date = models.DateField()

    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=191)

    language = models.CharField(max_length=191)

    print_length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='written_by')

    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='book photos', null=True,blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Show Migrations:**

```
book
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20180819_2147
 [X] 0003_auto_20180819_2147
 [X] 0004_auto_20180819_2148
 [X] 0005_auto_20180819_2151
 [X] 0006_auto_20180819_2152
 [X] 0007_auto_20180819_2154
 [X] 0008_auto_20180819_2155
 [X] 0009_auto_20180819_2159
 [X] 0010_auto_20180819_2201
 [X] 0011_book_photo
 [X] 0012_auto_20180826_1502
 [X] 0013_auto_20180828_2214
 [X] 0014_book_slug
```

**Table status:**

```
mysql> describe book_book;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title         | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pub_date      | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| publisher     | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| language      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| print_length  | decimal(6,0)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price         | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| quantity      | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description   | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_date  | datetime(6)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active     | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_modified | datetime(6)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| photo         | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**0014_book_slug.py:**

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('book', '0013_auto_20180828_2214'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='book',
            name='slug',
            field=models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you add the result of **`python manage.py showmigrations`**?

Comment: @JPG sure. done

Comment: This seems, your migration `0014_book_slug`  already applied to the DB

Comment: @JPG will it exist like a column in a table? there is no such a column called slug in the table.

Comment: Are you sure about that ?  try these commands one by one, **`python manage.py app_name zero`** then **`python manage.py app_name`**

Comment: @JPG I'm pretty sure, I keep checking the table status of the db in mysql. I'll add that result as well

Comment: Anyway, run the above two commands and add the results to question

Comment: @CAn you also add the `0014_book_slug.py` migartion file?

Comment: @JPG I run them, it tells "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Table 'book_author' already exists"

Comment: @JPG added, here we go

Comment: @JPG I run python manage.py migrate book zero, then run python manage.py migrate --fake book. Still not adding a new field into the table

Comment: why would you run --fake?  that tells django to tag it as if it were applied, but do nothing.  If you want the migration run, just use `python manage.py migrate book`

Comment: I have no idea why this happening. One solution is, **if you are not in production**, drop the DB and re-create a new one

Comment: @RishiG python manage.py migrate book does nothing, and when I load any of the webpages, it will throw an error "Unknown column 'book_book.slug' in 'field list'"

Comment: @Jinx : Can you execute "select * from django_migrations" and check if "0014_book_slug" entry is present in the table?

Comment: @Jinx : If you could not see "0014_book_slug" in django_migrations table, possible reason could be that you are looking at the wrong database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common problems that could apply to your case. Either you faked the migration (you did not apply it to database) or you are looking at the wrong database.

First check if maybe django is connected to a different database. The fastest way is to run shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and try creating an object with slug field.

```
from apps.books.models import Book
Book.objects.create(
    slug="something"
    # Enter all other r
)
```

If it works, slug field is set and you were probably connected to another database that already had it migrated. If it informs you that slug does not exist, you probably faked the migration.

If you somehow faked the migration, you should roll back to migration 0013.
(EDITED: added --fake)

```
python manage.py migrate book 0013 --fake
```

And then migrate the slug again

```
python manage.py migrate book
```

That should work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm doing this to the proper db/table. When I run `python manage.py migrate 0013'`, it will say `Can't DROP 'slug'; check that column/key exists`. And if I do something like `Book.objects.fitler(slug='something')`, it will say `Unknown column 'book_book.slug' in 'field list'`.

Comment: Try "python manage.py migrate book 0013 --fake", I forgot to write --fake in the answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Can u edit your answer then I accept and upvote?